# Is the John Simm version of the Master returning to Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

I just watched the Doctor Who episode 'Eaters of Light' and in the preview of the next episode it showed Missy dancing with the Doctor and John Simm smirking that classics evil smile. Is John Simm returning to replace Michelle Gomez as the new/old Master?

I would love to see this happen since John Simm is my favorite 'Master' [image]

Comment: Actually, I think it's John Simm that she's dancing with. It may also be her that he's addressing when he says, "Give us a kiss" in the trailer. *Flirting with himself - true love at last.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes.

This was confirmed by the BBC all the way back in April. From [this article](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/doctor-who/news/a825362/john-simm-returns-doctor-who-series-10-the-master-in/):

> "I can confirm that it's true, thanks to the power of time travel I'm back," Simm said. "It's always a pleasure to work with this great team of people and I can't wait for you all to see what The Master gets up to in the next series."

Comment: Man I can't wait then!! John Simm has to be one of my favorite Doctor Who characters (Next to John Barrowman as Captain Jack that is!)